# Quartz.Net Scheduler to Run as a Windows Services

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

This is first post on regarding the Quartz.net in this group. Hope will find my answers.

I am really new to work with Quartz.Net. One of our customer wanted us to schedule the tasks in Quartz instead of writing a Own scheduler logic.

Initially, i did some samples and tried out with the sample tasks (not so handy on that). I feel little bit cumbersome in working with Quartz.Net.

What we really wanted is,

1.) First How to Configure and Setup Quartz.Net to run as a Windows Services

2.) We have to run the Quartz as a Windows Services and should look for the Scheduled Time of the job and invoke.

3.) Then How to Integrate our Quartz Logic to the Service.

I Googled and got the links on how to Setup the service http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx

and i was mere success on setting it up, but after when  i Looked the below link

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/17/quartz.net-writing-your-first-hello-world-job.aspx

Here i have some questions, the Quartz.Net Service directory path ie "C:\Program Files(x86)\Quartz.Net" whether it will be created automatically or we nee to create that one.

After doing all the pasting the job to the Quartz then what is the purpose of coming back and hitting F5 in the project.

Any helps.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to implement the windows service yourself. In the OnStart event initialize and start the instance of quartz.net.
In the OnStop event make sure to stop quartz.
That's pretty much it.

Comment: is it?, as far as answers go while correct it still pretty poor.

Comment: Sorry @Lankymart I don't fully get what you mean